# bootstrap.min.css size from cdn shows a surprising size in devtools

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

**In firefox**
[image]

**In chrome**
[image]

Could someone explain why the size in devtools is 24.5KB ?

I load the bootstrap from this cdn : [bootstrap.min.css](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css)

***ps***: the cache was flushed during the test.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR Firefox shows the decompressed file size, Chrome shows the compressed file size**

To load pages faster and use less data most modern browsers download compressed versions of files from a WWW server. Let's make an experiment:

- Download the bootstrap.min.css file
- Compress it with `gzip -k bootstrap.min.css`
- Compare the file sizes:

  - Compressed version: ~20KB
  - Uncompressed version: ~116KB

I belive that Firefox displays the decompressed file size and Chrome displays the size of the file, which it downloaded (compressed).